# How can I have one program fill in the form of another vb.net forms program

Tags: .net

I have a VB.NET forms program which has fields and an OK button (I call it prog1).
I would like to have another vb.net program that reads data from a file, enters the data into the fields in prog1 and then presses the OK button in prog1.

Is this possible ? How ?

I know that it would be easier to do in one program but for certain reasons I am not allowed access to the code of prog1.

Thank You

( if you send me a reference to a C# program that would also be helpful )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`SendKeys` class in .NET Framework will help you achieve this easily. You can learn more about `SendKeys` at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx).

What you need to do is to use `FileStream` or some other stream reading class to parse the contents of your file and then send them to Prog1 using `SendKeys.Send()` function. `Send()` function works as if those keys were typed by the user through the keyboard, so you can send TAB, RETURN and other control keys as well, plus modifiers such as CTRL and SHIFT. That should be all you need for this purpose.

Comment: I hope I didn't inadvertently  down vote. I might have pressed one of the arrows by mistake without realizing that was how one votes (I don't use the site much for asking questions)  If so Iapologize. When I did realize that it was for voting I tried to up arrow and down arrow and was told by botht that I didn't have enough points to do it . Could someone else have done it ?
In any case Thank you for your response which has been helpful. There seems to be a timing problem which a delay  (System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) ) helps with.
I'll try to chose your answer and hopeit'llraise ur pnts